# How to exit if LOCK

Tags: c#, locking

I am trying to make a thread safe method. I have this code to test it.

```
private static readonly Object objLock = new Object();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        // Create ten new threads.
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            ThreadStart start = new ThreadStart(LockTest);
            new Thread(start).Start();
        }

        Console.Read();
    }

    public static void LockTest()
    {
        lock (objLock)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Environment.TickCount).Seconds.ToString());
        }
    }
```

This works but what I would like to do is if the Lock is in place I  need the other threads to exit rather than wait and execute the code when the lock is freed. Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [Monitor Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor(v=vs.110).aspx) which gives you more functionality than the lock. It's basically the same for standard lock usages.

Use the TryEnter function to see if you can acquire the lock. If not, then just exit the thread. Don't forget to release the lock manually though.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the `lock (objLock) { ...}` wird be converted into

`Monitor.Enter(objLock );
try
{
...
}
finally
{
    Monitor.Exit(objLock);
}`

Probably you can use the `Monitor.TryEnter(objLock, TimeSpan.Zero)` instead of `Monitor.Enter(objLock)` to try get the lock without waiting.

I didn't use `TimeSpan.Zero` with Monitor before, so try it first.